# getting error in node js "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say “I'm getting error in node js while probably while login or when code crashes ie, Error: Can't set headers after they are sent?”

```
err: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
      at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
      at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
      at basicAuthentication (/home/brainmobi/git/Abhijeet/Node/qarari_backend/lib/middleware/basicAuth.js:16:16)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brainmobi/git/Abhijeet/Node/qarari_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at trim_prefix (/home/brainmobi/git/Abhijeet/Node/qarari_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
      at /home/brainmobi/git/Abhijeet/Node/qarari_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
      at Function.process_params (/home/brainmobi/git/Abhijeet/Node/qarari_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: Did you have a question? Is there something unclear about the error message? Are you expecting us to be able to tell how to fix the code you haven't shown us?

Comment: Could you please share some code, So we can work with some context !

Comment: Please add your code - you're most likely using `res.send` (in Express) or another `res` method twice.

Comment: you need to show us code as to give us context, also the issue could simply be that after the response is sent, you cannot do subsequent actions to your response.

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js and almost every server languages, you can not set another header after some headers are already sent in a single response to the client.

**For Example, this use case will not work**

```js
app.get('/', (err, res) => {
res.send('Hello!'); // This will send a response to the client, along with the appropriate headers.

res.send('How are you?!'); // This will throw the same error as you are getting before a response along with some headers are already sent
})
```